# some font-sizes are giving unexpected scroll on one-line text

Tags: css, scroll

I was trying to find every inconsistent scrollHeight/offsetHeight on a page I am working on, and stumbled upon this. Some elements had 1px difference between scrollHeight/offsetHeight. I was able to narrow the problem down to this.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/mixtur/pen/KYaWWN)

html:

```html
<div>Text</div>
```

css:

```css
div {
  font-size: 17px
  overflow: auto
}
```

When we are changing font-size sometimes there is little 1px scroll appearing. Can anyone explain why that is happening? I only have one line in div. Why doesn't it stretch that div's height properly? Can I avoid it somehow? This is very annoying.

I only tried in Chrome and Firefox on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a `line-height` issue, in conjunction with `overflow: auto`.

Here's a replication of your codepen. The only difference is that I set a default `line-height: 1` (if you inspect the `div` in your codepen, you can see the `div` is inheriting that `line-height: 1` by default):

```css
div {
  font-size: 17px;
  overflow: auto;

  /* default line-height */
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eget interdum urna, eget tristique tellus. Phasellus pharetra blandit nisl, non venenatis arcu efficitur nec. Nulla facilisi. Ut at ante quis risus posuere varius. Aenean fringilla dui non sem hendrerit volutpat. Pellentesque mattis libero at volutpat malesuada. Aliquam in lobortis orci, vel condimentum tellus. Ut dignissim ligula sed nulla blandit vestibulum. Cras eleifend, orci eget rhoncus faucibus, massa lacus accumsan mauris, eget efficitur mauris est non nisl. Morbi vel nulla a urna pretium varius.
</div>
```

If you set an appropriate `line-height` for your 17px text, you won't have the scrolling issue. For example:

```css
div {
  font-size: 17px;
  overflow: auto;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eget interdum urna, eget tristique tellus. Phasellus pharetra blandit nisl, non venenatis arcu efficitur nec. Nulla facilisi. Ut at ante quis risus posuere varius. Aenean fringilla dui non sem hendrerit volutpat. Pellentesque mattis libero at volutpat malesuada. Aliquam in lobortis orci, vel condimentum tellus. Ut dignissim ligula sed nulla blandit vestibulum. Cras eleifend, orci eget rhoncus faucibus, massa lacus accumsan mauris, eget efficitur mauris est non nisl. Morbi vel nulla a urna pretium varius.
</div>
```

Basically, if the `line-height` is less than or equal to the `font-size`, and `overflow` is set to `auto`, the scrolling issue appears. If `overflow` property is removed, and `line-height` is still less than or equal to the `font-size`, the scrolling issue goes away.

Here's exactly what `overflow: auto` does, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow):

> **auto**
> Depends on the user agent. If content fits inside the padding box, it looks the same as visible, but still establishes a new block formatting context. Desktop browsers provide scrollbars if content overflows.

Essentially with this `overflow` property set, when your `line-height` clips the font, you get the scrollbar.

Comment: well yes, but no) I mean it is a workaround not really a solution. I don't want to do it manually for every font/font-size combination. Also 20px seems lika a magical number to me. Where is it came from?

Comment: @mixture 20px is just an example. If you set the `line-height` to _anything_ greater than 17px, the font isn't clipped. So 18px+ works.

Comment: well if I use font-size: 170px, then 171px for line-height won't work, 187 does work though.

Comment: ok line-height: 1.11 seems to work on every font-size with default font. But this is still a workaround. Ideally I would prefer a way to change font-rendering and/or layout logic in such way that problem would not appear at all.